# How do you make jQuery animate an element smoothly after external content has loaded into it?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've tried different variations of the code example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#demo').hide();
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("#demo").load("demo.php").show('medium');
   });
});
```

...but the animation "jumps", and is not smooth. It's like the `show()` function assumes the hidden `#demo` element was smaller than it is with the new external information loaded into it. There is nothing in the `#demo` element until `load()` puts it there, so it starts out smaller than after the external content is loaded into it.

How can I make `show()` "understand" that `#demo` is in fact bigger with the loaded content in it, so it animates smoothly when activated?

Comment: Try putting the `show` in the load callback.

Comment: Tried, but I can't get it to work. How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [complete callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) in [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var demo = $('#demo');

    demo.hide();
    $("button").click(function(){
        demo.load('demo.php', function() {
            demo.show('medium');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Very good and informative answer! Also I learned a better way to set things up with the way you set that variable. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#demo").load("demo.php",function() {
    $("#demo").show('medium')
});
```

The page is loading while the animation is going "medium" speed to show the container.  Use the show function in the callback of load.

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: You could also show #demo first, then load the php.  You could use a loading graphic going that route